# ZFS - setting physical disk start point of pool/filesystem

Tags: filesystems, hard-drive, zfs, raidz

I'm testing harddisk performance, and would like to test writing to the outer tracks of my harddisk with ZFS. One way of doing this would be to create a pool/filesystem with a start point just a few Gigs away from the end of my harddisk.

Is this possible? If so, how do I do it? I've looked in zfs man pages and googled, but couldn't find what I'm looking for.

Furthermore, I'd like to create a RAIDZ1 using only the last part (outer tracks) of my HDDs the same way - for performance testing purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term you're referring to is "[short-stroking](http://www.overclock.net/hard-drives-storage/609576-short-stroke-why-how.html)". You can do this by creating a pool of [disk *slices*](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/ggxoj/index.html) rather than the whole disks. Use some small percentage of the disk (10%-12%) capacity for the slices.

This may not be worth it, though. Use faster disks and SSDs since ZFS can leverage them well.

Comment: Ah, so I create disk slices in the OS first, and then a ZFS using these slices? I thought ZFS pools had to be placed on top of entire disks.

Comment: You can use disk slices in your ZFS pool. You just have to use the slice designation in your zpool create command.

Comment: You may actually end up with worse performance if you use slices instead of whole disks, due to the way ZFS handles the [disk write cache](http://www.solarisinternals.com/wiki/index.php/ZFS_Best_Practices_Guide#Storage_Pools)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to slices already rightly suggested by ewwhite, you can also use plain primary partitions a ZFS low level device if you are running on x86 architecture, and even logical ones if on a recent OpenSolaris build, Solaris 11 Express or newer.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Once I understood that zfs accepts block devices other than just entire disks, it opened up a lot more flexibility to me :-)

Comment: ZFS even accepts plain files, although not recommended for anything but testing purposes.